# Why I can't plot this function in matlab? What's wrong with my code?

Tags: matlab, function, plot

I just want to plot the function h(x,y)=(xsin(20y)+ysin(20x))^2cosh(sin(10x)x)+(xcos(10y)−ysin(10x))^2cosh(cos(20y)y)
and I have the code

```
clear;
close all;
h=inline('(x*sin(20*y)+y*sin(20*x)).^2*cosh(sin(10*x)*x)+(x*cos(10*y)-y*sin(10*x)).^2*cosh(cos(20*y)*y)','x','y');

x=-3:0.01:3;
y=-3:0.01:3;
for i=1:length(x)
    z(:,i)=h(x(i),y);
end
figure(1);
mesh(x,y,z);
xlabel('x','fontsize',14);
ylabel('y','fontsize',14);
zlabel('h(x,y)','fontsize',14);
```

Why it always gives the response:

Error using inlineeval (line 14)
Error in inline expression ==>
(x*sin(20*y)+y*sin(20*x)).^2*cosh(sin(10*x)*x)+(x*cos(10*y)-y*sin(10*x)).^2*cosh(cos(20*y)*y)
 Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Error in inline/subsref (line 23)
    INLINE_OUT_ = inlineeval(INLINE_INPUTS_, INLINE_OBJ_.inputExpr,
    INLINE_OBJ_.expr);

Error in hw7_2 (line 8)
    z(:,i)=h(x(i),y);

This is why? Any help will be appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error message says it all really, `Inner matrix dimensions must agree.`. Matlab error messages are very useful, always read them!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant to use *pointwise* multiplication (`.*`) instead of matrix multiplication (`*`).  I.e. instead of `x*sin(20*y)` you should use `x.*sin(20*y)`, etc.  This will mutliply each *element* of the array `x` by each *element* of the array `sin(20*y)`, which is likely the desired behavior.